# How to write 40 minutes in Postgresql interval

Tags: postgresql

I read the Postgresql documentation but I still can't understand how to write the interval when I'm adding data to the table. I want to put 40 minutes through OmniDBs interface but I'm oblivious about the format to write it in.

Comment: `interval '40' minute`

Comment: Tried, get syntax error near '40':
syntax error at or near "40"
LINE 1: ...lues ( 1, 1, 1, 'Cook the chicken', 1, interval ''40'' minut...

Comment: try single quotes

Comment: It doesn't paste right for some reason, I did use single quotes. Copy pasted what you wrote

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm using a GUI IDE to setup my database and I selected one format as interval as I thought it would be smart to have cooking time as an interval but the documentation is quite rubbish about it. Doesn't give you one concrete example and googling postgreSQL interval input format doesn't yield much global knowledge

Comment: That syntax **is** valid: http://rextester.com/PJFI73386

Comment: Oh well, 100% sure the data type is interval and 100% sure I input it in exactly that way and 100% sure I have a postgreSQL database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - you are correct, but is that documented somewhere? pg docs don't mention that form AFAICT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's several ways. here are some.

```
select
interval '40' minute   ,-- using the minute keyword
interval '40 minute'   ,-- string description
interval '0:40'        ,-- hours and minutes
40 * interval '1m'    ,-- using arithmetic on 1 minute
'0:40:00'::interval    ,-- hours minutes and seconds, with a cast
'40 minutes'::interval ,-- string with a cast
interval '2400'        ;-- that many seconds
```

note: the keyword must be `minute` but in a string description `minutes`, `m`, and `min` also work.

for inserts into a table where postgres knows the type that the values should be coerced to the cast or interval keyword may be optional

```
insert into times (t) values 
   (interval '40' minute ), -- using keyword interval also needed
   ('40 minute'          ), -- string description 
   ('0:40'               ), -- 0 hours and 40 minutes
   (40 * interval '1 m'  ), -- for arithmetic interval is needed
   ('0:40:00'            ), -- h:m:s
   ('40 minutes'         ), -- string desc.
   ('2400'               ); -- 2400 seconds
```

documentation here
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT

But that doesn't describe the use of the keyword form.